# Android app build fails because of JAXB.unmarshal()

Tags: android, gradle, mobile, jaxb

Every time i try to build my android app, it  throws an error that looked like this

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Cannot invoke "javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.createUnmarshaller()" because "context" is null

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
```

I had added JAXB to the build if that was the problem, I even had to recreate a new project as the project is fairly small. The build was running when i first created the project but it is now rebelling.

Comment: Jaxb is a technology that has been removed from recent JRE versions, so if this is an old project make sure you also use a matching JRE (e.g. Java 8). Or you may need to update the used gradle plugins so that they use the replacent version jakarta.xml.bind https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jaxb-ri/